# Issue: Bootstrap Tour Error with 'tip' property

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-tour

### Issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tip')

#### Description:

I'm facing a challenge when trying to implement a tour on my website using the Bootstrap Tour library. While the tour correctly identifies the elements, it fails to display the content and title as expected.
and i also included the Jquery and Bootstrap CDN in before this CDN.

#### Code Sample:

```js
function startTour() {
    var labtour = new Tour({
        name: "labtour",
        storage: window.localStorage,
        debug: true,
    });

    labtour.addSteps([{
        element: "#lab-tour",
        title: "Lab",
        content: "This is the lab. You can create and manage your experiments here.",
        placement: "bottom",
        backdrop: true,
        animation: true,
    }, {
        element: "#lab-tour-1",
        title: "Lab",
        content: "This is the lab. You can create and manage your experiments here.",
        placement: "right",
        backdrop: true,
        animation: true,
    }]);
    labtour.init();
    labtour.start();
}
```

#### Error Stack Trace:

```
bootstrap-tour.js:597  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tip')
    at Tour._showPopover (bootstrap-tour.js:597:113)
    at Tour._showPopoverAndOverlay (bootstrap-tour.js:552:18)
    at Tour._showPopoverAndOverlay (bootstrap-tour.js:22:61)
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-tour.js:717:31)
    at r.complete (jquery.min.js?_=v0.4-beta-555-gb4f99e00:2:62910)
    at c (jquery.min.js?_=v0.4-beta-555-gb4f99e00:2:28327)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?_=v0.4-beta-555-gb4f99e00:2:29072)
    at u (jquery.min.js?_=v0.4-beta-555-gb4f99e00:2:59642)
    at S.fx.tick (jquery.min.js?_=v0.4-beta-555-gb4f99e00:2:64608)
    at ot (jquery.min.js?_=v0.4-beta-555-gb4f99e00:2:58967)
```

##### I'm using CDN link is here:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.12.0/js/bootstrap-tour.js" integrity="sha512-2J1oe/iXZZroN8TQl1kbLBqBGp2zyulBVw9IXnFb/Iun6YppB6qncJB0xjkYjsMr+KdiYs5Fs787pjSaeW43Mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

#### Additional Context:

All dependencies have been verified to load correctly and in the appropriate order. I'm seeking insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.

- I attempted to implement a guided tour on my website using the Bootstrap Tourist library. I initialized the tour with specific steps targeting elements #lab-tour and #lab-tour-1 and expected the tour to guide users through these elements with the specified content and title.
- I expected the tour to start and guide users through the specified steps, displaying the content and title for each step. The tour should highlight the elements #lab-tour and #lab-tour-1 with a backdrop and provide the associated content and title.
- The tour failed to display as expected, and I encountered an error in the console related to the Bootstrap Tourist library. The specific error message was not provided, but it seems to be related to the initialization or attachment of the tour to the specified elements.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZmhG.png)